# Is it possible to close a PDA account directly in typescript?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, pda

I want to close an account directly in the typescript code, instead of writing it in the smart contract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closing an Account is just deducting an Account lamports balance to zero and making sure the data field is empty. Only a Program can deduct the lamports from a PDA, hence It is not possible to close a PDA Account from the Client(typescript).